# .NET 4.0 Chart Control not working with Dotnetnuke

Tags: .net, charts, dotnetnuke

As many of you know, .NET 4.0 incorporated the chart control, which is awesome in that you can pretty much build all the chart types you see in Excel directly into your .NET application.

After a bit of digging around, I finally got the control to work in my application (mostly Web.config additions). However, when I try to rewrite my code as a dotnetnuke 5 module, it stopped working. it looks like all the configs are in place, but for some reason the image just won't show up.

Has anyone encountered this before? Is it a routing problem? or a handler problem?

any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [downloading](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c&DisplayLang=en) the and using version for .NET 3.5 instead.  It's almost identical, but may have less compatibility problems.  Just a wild guess.

Comment: the .NET 4.0 version did work on my computer, which runs IIS 7.5, I've read about the configuration differences in IIS 6.x and 7.x, and now I'm not exactly sure what else I can do 'cause it seems like all the handlers are in place...